# Is it ok to use SSAID (aka ANDROID_ID) value for encryption keys?

Tags: java, android, android-8.0-oreo

I have seen some Android apps that use the `ANDROID_ID` (SSAID - Secure Settings Android ID) as a light-weight tool to calculate an encryption key that is only known to that application/device/user to protect data at rest. While I can not see any obvious weakness (assuming device is not rooted as all the `ANDROID_ID`s can be enumerated), the documentation does not touch on this subject (event to advise against it). Thus, I am wondering if anyone know any issues with the scheme?

--

Below is some motivation about why it appears to be secure on non-rooted devices.

--

Android developer documentation (for API > 26) states the following about [ANDROID_ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID):

> On Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher versions of the platform, a 64-bit number (expressed as a hexadecimal string), unique to each combination of app-signing key, user, and device. Values of ANDROID_ID are scoped by signing key and user. The value may change if a factory reset is performed on the device or if an APK signing key changes.

There is also the following in a [blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/04/changes-to-device-identifiers-in.html) post:

> In O, Android ID (Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID or SSAID) has a different value for each app and each user on the device. Developers requiring a device-scoped identifier, should instead use a resettable identifier, such as Advertising ID, giving users more control. Advertising ID also provides a user-facing setting to limit ad tracking.
>   Additionally in Android O:
>
> - The ANDROID_ID value won't change on package uninstall/reinstall, as long as the package name and signing key are the same. Apps can rely on this value to maintain state across reinstalls.
> - If an app was installed on a device running an earlier version of Android, the Android ID remains the same when the device is updated to Android O, unless the app is uninstalled and reinstalled.
> - The Android ID value only changes if the device is factory reset or if the signing key rotates between uninstall and reinstall events.
> - This change is only required for device manufacturers shipping with Google Play services and Advertising ID. Other device manufacturers may provide an alternative resettable ID or continue to provide ANDROID ID.

Moreover, looking at the source code for [SettingsProvider.java](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/packages/SettingsProvider/src/com/android/providers/settings/SettingsProvider.java) where the SSAID is calculated, it appears that the process is as follows:

1. each device user is assigned a 32 byte random key.
2. for each APK: hmac with sha256 is used to calculate the SSAID over the APK signer keys (where the key used is that generated in step 1).
3. hmac is truncated to 16 characters.
4. the truncated value is saved to `settings_ssaid.xml` (future requests for the `ANDROID_ID` are looked up from this file).

Thus, the security appears to be entirely held on the secrecy of the key generated in step 1 (which is also stored in `settings_ssaid.xml`).

Comment: Hi, could theoretically someone used the ANDROID_ID to attempt a bruteforce attack in order to find users password? In this case the attacker would only need the 32byte random key generated for the user, right?

Comment: @Lango As far as I know this has nothing to do with user credentials. It is just a technique to generate a unique id for each app on each device for each user.

Comment: yes thats what I realized by reading the official documentation, thanks!!